# Error routes in phalcon ..how to resolve this configuration?

Tags: phalcon

> Hello some one can help me i have installed phalcon 3.4 -v but the router dont work
> correctly in my server localhost ??

[Router.php image]
[image: 1]

[index.php image]
[image: 2]

[Error page on localhost]
[image: 3]

[.htaccess in project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ZFA.png)
[.htaccess in public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEvA0.png)

Comment: You're missing a number of required steps.  I would suggest reading the documentation again - specifically the web server setup section–https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/webserver-setup– and the basic tutorial: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/tutorial-basic.  And for future reference, paste and format your code in your question, rather than linking images.

Comment: That's not a Phalcon error. You're seeing an Apache 404 error. If you blank out your index.php file and put some test output, you'll see the same 404 error. Make sure you have an .htaccess file and it routes to the index.php file for such 404s using for example RewriteRule. Make sure you remember RewriteEngine on. Make sure the rewrite apache module is enabled. And also make sure your apache config uses AllowOverride All so it will read from your .htaccess file.

Comment: But the documentation write the .htaccess in that manner. So?

Comment: look please .htaccess in project folder .htaccess in public folder